# Firebase create user "manually"

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the standard Email + Password auth-provider.

Through certain circumstances I have to create a firebase user manually. The flow would be something like calling a REST api with an defined email + generated password, and if succeeded sending a welcome email to the user with his password. Something like forward user registration.

I read through their docs and couldn't find much. (the new docs don't even offer a REST API section for user management.. well and just to be clear, the new "google" styled docs, pretty much suck anyway :) ).

Is there someone who has already done something similar and can help me out?

BTW: It would also be possible to create them client side through `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, but this function does automatically reauthenticate the new user, which must not happen in my scenario. Is it possible to use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` without automatically logging in the user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a new Firebase App context in your client and then call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` there:

```
var authApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  // ...
}, 'authApp');
var detachedAuth = authApp.auth();

detachedAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword('foo@example.com', 'asuperrandompassword');
```

By adding a second argument to `initializeApp` you create a separate context that will *not* trigger re-authentication upon user creation.

Comment: This is a great solution. I didn't think of this

Comment: @michael-bleigh is there any way for creating users with only phone numbers? I am building a solution for people who don't have emails and only have phone numbers. I am finding it hard to create accounts for them.