# Firebase register once, login on different apps

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a website and multiple android apps that all use firebase for authentication. The website and the apps all are associated with separate firebase projects with their own separate auth and database, the auth is done via firebase's email-password authentication.

**I want to know if it is possible for the user to register in one app and having a duplicate account created for the website and vice versa.**

So if a user registers in an app, they can login into the website without registering again.

I don't think firebase has a rest api for authentication.

***EDIT:*** 
The answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553362/firebase-create-user-manually?rq=1) by [Michael Bleigh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/226391/michael-bleigh) will most likely work if i put it inside a rest api accessible by all my apps

***Solved:*** I implemented the answer provided in the link above inside an api and it works,

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication accounts are specific to the Firebase project, not to the app. So if a user logs in to the Android app first, they can subsequently log in to the Web app with the same credentials and end up in the same user account.

Comment: I'm sorry, i should have been clearer, All of my apps and the website use different firebase projects since i want each of them to have separate databases. Also each android app needs too have its own distinct auth from the other android apps.