# Adding multiple users to Firebase using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to set up a page using Angular, where an admin with requisite permissions can add users using Firebase 'username' and 'password' authentication.

I have been lurking around stackoverflow for answers. I have found :
[Firebase create user "manually"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553362/firebase-create-user-manually)
and this:
[Firebase kicks out current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user/37614090#37614090)

Going by the answers, I think they have achieved this by not using the Admin SDK and by bypassing the re-authentication that happens after a user is registered.

Problem is, I am a newbie and I am working in Angular. I was told to add the API keys and everything in the environment.ts and then add the Initialize method to the app.module.ts. How do I go about this special use case? The procedure I follow could be wrong altogether. I am trying to wrap my head around this. Any help or a link to any resource online would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: Doesn't the admin SDK require node? I was hoping to have angular as front end and firebase as backend. Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: You can use Angular and Firebase for front end and Firebase functions for backend - https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/. you don't need a separate Node server.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of some solution of this kind: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps. I think this is the same solution implemented in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553362/firebase-create-user-manually. But how do I do this in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

Well in the end it goes this way.

- Keep the regular initilize.app method in your app.module.ts.
- Initialize the App again as a separate service (or wherever) with a separate name, which would be something like initialize.app(config,"secondary"); - The "secondary" thing is important. Call it any name, I just added it as secondary. Add users with this initialization. *config* is your API key and other files you get from firebase.
- Because of this "secondary" initialization there would not be any re-authentication of the user.

Phew. Thats like two days of work. lol.

Comment: That was the same thing that was being said in the links that I gave in the question earlier. But, https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/761 helped me out as I was confused where to add the secondary initialization in angular, whether it is the app.module or elsewhere.